# My readfile is working in debug mode but not release mode. What's going wrong?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, file-io, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

Currently testing on the 512 MB emulator.  I have the following code that performs properly in debug mode:

```
StorageFolder^ appFolder = Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current->InstalledLocation;

String^ path = appFolder->Path;

std::wstring testFileName = std::wstring(path->Begin(), path->End()) + std::wstring(L"\\full-R23-0000000000000000Mapped");

_CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS extend = { 0 };
extend.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
extend.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
extend.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED;
extend.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_ANONYMOUS;
extend.lpSecurityAttributes = nullptr;
extend.hTemplateFile = nullptr;

HANDLE dataFile = CreateFile2(
    testFileName.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    OPEN_ALWAYS,
    &extend);

DWORD errcode = GetLastError();
OutputDebugString(L" Error Code: ");
OutputDebugString(std::to_wstring(errcode).c_str());

OVERLAPPED positionalData = { 0 };
positionalData.Offset = 0;
positionalData.OffsetHigh = 0;
positionalData.hEvent = 0;


byte* cacheTest = reinterpret_cast<byte*>(VirtualAlloc(
    NULL,
    datasetReadSectorSize,
    MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
    PAGE_READWRITE));

bool readsuccess = ReadFile(
    dataFile,
    &cacheTest[0],
    datasetReadSectorSize,
    NULL,
    &positionalData);

DWORD errcode2 = GetLastError();
OutputDebugString(L" Error Code 2: ");
OutputDebugString(std::to_wstring(errcode2).c_str());

DWORD temp_sector_size = datasetReadSectorSize;

GetOverlappedResult(
    dataFile,
    &positionalData,
    &temp_sector_size,
    true);
```

However, this code hangs on the last GetOverlappedResult command in release mode.  In debug mode, the error codes that it gives are 183 and 997 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS and ERROR_IO_PENDING, respectively), neither of which are problems here.  In release mode, the error codes that it gives are 183 and 38 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS and ERROR_HANDLE_EOF, respectively).  That it's getting an End of File error here certainly puzzles me.  The file that it's accessing is part of the project, and in its configuration properties, it's set to Excluded from build: NO (I've tried both ways with this setting), Content: YES (setting this to yes was crucial for making debug mode work), and Item type: Does not participate in build (I haven't touched this setting).

How can I make release mode behave consistently with debug mode (in this case, successfully perform the fileio)?

Comment: This isn't C++, but some dialect (probably C++/CLI). Please retag accordingly.

Comment: It isn't C++/CLI, that isn't supported on windows phone.  However, point is taken.

Comment: Looks like the traditional broken error handling that is so common in winapi code.  Displaying the value of GetLastError() when the winapi function did not actually fail produces a random number.

Comment: @HansPassant that's not true here.  GetLastError() will produce 0 if there is nothing to note.  Error_Already_Exists can be an error or not depending on the parameters fed to CreateFile2 (If the Create_New flag is set, this results in a failure.  If the Open_Always flag is set, Error_Already_Exists indicates a success).  Error_Io_Pending likewise can indicate success when dealing with asynchronous io.  Error_Handle_Eof is the legitimate problem, and is popping up consistently (again, only in release mode).

Comment: Well, of course not.  That you think that's true is pretty obvious from the code.  That doesn't make it true.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry, I'm not sure I'm understanding what claim you're making here.  Are you saying that that the the Error_Already_Exists flag is random?  Or that the Error_Io_Pending is random?  There is extensive documentation (and my own experience validates this) to suggest that those two error codes occur during this sort of fileio.  I suspect that I'm misunderstanding you, could you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is pretty embarrassing because the answer is so simple.  When I added the file I was reading from (I added it while it was in a debug build), editing the property page, I never changed the configuration property from "Debug" to "All configurations".  Changing that solved my problem, and now ReadFile works in release mode as it did in debug mode.

I'd been barking up so many wrong trees.